# Submission form is not properly submitting information to SQL (PHP and JS)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've made a jobs post form in which a user fills out and after submitting the form, the job should be displayed on the same page under it. for some reason, the job description and job location data that's returned comes up as undefined. I'm thinking it might be because they're a drop-down list and text area? but I can't see to fully comprehend why the error shows up. Also, how would I go about submitting radio buttons to a database? would they need specific values?

Below is the jobs.html page

```
<?php
//allow the config
define('__CONFIG__', true);
//require the config
require_once "inc/config.php";  //possibly have to change the location

Page::ForceLogin();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- UIKit CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.24/css/uikit.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <base href="/"/>
    <nav class="uk-navbar-container uk-margin"  uk-navbar>
        <div class="uk-navbar-left">

            <a class="uk-navbar-item uk-logo"  href="comp1687/index.php"><img src="/comp1687/jobswatchsmall.png" alt="sitelogo"></a>

            <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="comp1687/index.php">
                        <span class="uk-icon uk-margin-small-right" ></span>
                        <b>Home Page</b>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="comp1687/jobs.php">
                        <span class="uk-icon uk-margin-small-right" ></span>
                        <b>Jobs</b>
                    </a>
                </li>
        </div>

        <div class="uk-navbar-center">
            <div class="uk-navbar-item">
                <form action="javascript:void(0)">
                    <input class="uk-input uk-form-width-small" style="width:350px; border-radius: 10px; " type="text" placeholder="Input">
                    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default" style="border-radius: 10px;">Button</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="uk-navbar-right">
            <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="comp1687/about.php">
                        <span class="uk-icon uk-margin-small-right" ></span>
                        <b>About Us</b>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="comp1687/dashboard.php">
                        <span class="uk-icon uk-margin-small-right" ></span>
                        <b>Profile Page</b>
                    </a>
                </li>
        </div>

    </nav>


</head>
<body>

<div class="uk-section uk-container">
    <div class="uk-grid uk-child-width-1-3@s uk-child-width-1-1" uk-grid></div>

    <h2><b><center>Jobs</center></b></h2>

    <div style="border: 3px solid #ddd; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px;">
    <h4><center>Welcome to the job browsing section. You are able to browse the available jobs below, and if desired, you may post your own job!</center></h4>
    <div class="jobspost" style="border: 3px solid #ddd; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px;">
        <h4><center><b>Post a job</b></center></h4>
        <form class="uk-form-stacked js-jobs">
            <fieldset class="uk-fieldset">



                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text"><b>Job title:</b></label>
                    <input id="jobTitle" class="uk-input" type="text" required placeholder="Insert the name of the job">
                </div>
                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text"><b>Skills required:</b></label>
                    <input id="jobSkills" class="uk-input" type="text" required placeholder="Insert the skills needed for the job">
                </div>
                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text"><b>Job description:</b></label>
                    <textarea id="jobDescription" class="uk-textarea" rows="5" required placeholder="Insert a description of the job"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text"><b>Images (If necessary):</b></label>
                    <input id="jobImage" class="uk-button uk-button-default" type="file" name="jobImage" >
                </div>

                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text"><b>Job location:</b></label>
                    <select id="jobLocation" required class="uk-select">
                        <option>-Select a region of london for the jobs location-</option>
                        <option>-------CENTRAL-------</option>
                        <option>Camden</option>
                        <option>City of London</option>
                        <option>Kensington and Chelsea</option>

                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="uk-margin">
                    <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text"><b>Job reward:</b></label>
                    <input id="jobReward" class="uk-input" required type="text" placeholder="Insert the amount of credits this job is worth">
                </div>


                <div class="uk-margin uk-grid-small uk-child-width-auto uk-grid">
                    <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text"><b>Job status:</b></label>
                    <label><input id="jobStatus" class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="radio2" checked> Available</label>
                    <label><input id="jobStatus" class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="radio2"> Completed</label>
                </div>

                <center><button id="jobbtn" name="jobbtn" class="uk-button uk-button-default" type="submit"><b>SUBMIT JOB</b></button></center>
                <br>

            </fieldset>
        </form>

    </div>
      <br>
    <div class="jobsbrowse" style="border: 3px solid #ddd; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px;">
    <h4><center><b>Browse the jobs</b></center></h4>

     </div>
         </div>
</div>

<?php require_once "inc/footer.php"; ?> <!-- possibly have to change the location  -->


</body>
</html>
```

The code below is the ajax/jobs

```
<?php

//allow the config
define('__CONFIG__', true);

//require the config
require_once "../inc/config.php"; //possibly have to change the location

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    //Always return JSON format
    //header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $return = [];

    $jobTitle = Filter::String($_POST['jobTitle']);
    $jobSkills = Filter::String($_POST['jobSkills']);
    $jobDescription = Filter::String($_POST['jobDescription']);
    $jobLocation = Filter::String($_POST['jobLocation']);
    $jobReward = Filter::String($_POST['jobReward']);
    $jobStatus = Filter::String($_POST['jobStatus']);


    // make sure the user adds a job.
    $addJob = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO jobs(jobTitle, jobSkills, jobDescription, jobLocation, jobReward, jobStatus) VALUES(:jobTitle, :jobSkills, :jobDescription, :jobLocation, :jobReward, :jobStatus)");
    $addJob->bindParam(':jobTitle', $jobTitle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $addJob->bindParam(':jobSkills', $jobSkills, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $addJob->bindParam(':jobDescription', $jobDescription, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $addJob->bindParam(':jobLocation', $jobLocation, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $addJob->bindParam(':jobReward', $jobReward, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $addJob->bindParam(':jobStatus', $jobStatus, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $addJob->execute();

    // return the proper information back to Javascript to redirect us.

    echo json_encode($return, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
} else {
    //Kill the script. Redirect the user.
    exit('Invalid URL');
}


?>
```

The code below is the JS responsible for submittion.

```
.on("submit", "form.js-jobs", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var _form = $(this);
        var _error = $(".js-error", _form);

        var jobObj = {

            jobTitle: $("input[id='jobTitle']", _form) .val(),
            jobSkills: $("input[id='jobSkills']", _form) .val(),
            jobDescription: $("input[id='jobDescription']", _form) .val(),
            jobLocation: $("input[id='jobLocation']", _form) .val(),
            jobReward: $("input[id='jobReward']", _form) .val(),
            jobStatus: $("input[id='jobStatus']", _form) .val(),

        };

        if(jobObj.length < 1) {
            _error
                .text("Please fill in all fields.")
                .show();
            return false;
        }

        // Assuming the code gets this far, we can start the ajax process
        _error.hide();
        console.log(jobObj)
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'comp1687/ajax/jobs.php', //possibly have to change the location
            data: jobObj,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
        })
            .done(function ajaxDone(data) {
                // Whatever data is
                if(data.redirect !== undefined) {
                    window.location.reload();
                    console.log('data');
                } else if(data.error !== undefined) {
                    _error
                        .html(data.error)
                        .show();
                    console.log('data');
                }
            })
            .fail(function ajaxFailed(e) {
                //this failed
                console.log(e);

            })
            .always(function ajaxAlwaysDoThis(data) {
                //always do
                console.log('Always');
            })

        return false;
    })
```

Comment: Are you returning anything from ajax/jobs.php ?

Comment: @Abhishek Well I'm submitting the information to it, and then I want to to be displayed again on the same page, but in the form of a table, so people can constantly submit jobs to the table as they please

Comment: See your network under dev tool what is in returning data. Then inside your ajaxDone parse those data into html format and insert into div on the page.